# Dynamic query execution in mybatis/xml file

Tags: spring-mybatis, mybatis-sql

I have a spring boot application code from controller to dao in which I execute queries in mybatis/xml files. I want to pass the entire query as a variable to the dao and then it should get executed in mybatis and the result gets stored in the calling variable in dao?
The query would be a select statement with hardcoded parameters
How can I do that?

Comment: How far did you get?

Comment: not progressed til now.. couldn't find any reference for this

Answer (score 0):

You probably did something else by now, but you can write a mapper with a `sql` parameter and the following in the xml:

```
<select resultType="...">${sql}</select>
```